dbt execute the result of select statement
I'm reading the Oracle redo logs using dbt.
Simplified contents of the redo log are:

So, these are actual sql queries to execute.
My steps are:

Select these records
Execute queries that these records contain

My question is how to execute these queries using dbt?
